# Where is CZ gate in IBM Quantum circuit composer

Tags: quantum-gate, ibm-quantum-devices, ibm-q-experience

I am trying to build the Grover circuit using the IBM Quantum Composer circuit composer. The Grover example has a CZ gate. I can't find that gate in circuit composer.

Answer (score 6):

There is no Controlled-Z in the circuit composer by default because this gate can be built from CNOT ($CX$) and Hadamard gate $H$. This is because we have the identity
$$ Z = HXH$$
This implies that $CZ$ can be constructed as:

[image]

Now, in the qiskit composer, there is a button *+ Add* that allows you to add this gate operation as a pre-defined gate and you can named it as CZ gate.

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. The only downside I see is that the icon for the gate I add does not show the connection to the other qubit, only a box on line for one qubit. The cz gate for the Grover example shows a connection to both qubits.I am not sure how they did that. Are you allowed to design your own icons?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how it was in 2021, currently (Oct 2022) the way to create a CZ gate in the IBM Quantum Composer is:

1. Add a Z gate
2. Edit it
3. `Add control`
4. You can change the control and target qubit from the menu.

[image: how to create a CZ gate]